# Units in gravitational N-body simulations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, simulations, celestial-mechanics, unit-conversion

I use a code in Python to simulate a binary system interacting through gravity. You can find it [here](http://nbabel.org/codes/12); The code works fine. I am however having problems with the units of length and velocity.

I created a solarsystem with 3 particles and found distances for the binary stars (0.095 AU apart from each other). The circumbinary planet is in an orbit 0.88 AU from the center. The units of the integration are so called Heggie-Units, in which case M=G=1. I'd like to make an input file like [this one](http://nbabel.org/input) But I can't convert the units of length and velocity to the units the code uses. Since I don't know what those units are.

Comment: The mass of the stars are 0.75 M☉ each. The circumbinary planet has a mass of 1.011 M⊕ (3.035e-6 M☉). The M I mentioned concerns the total mass. I'm not sure what you mean by conventional units. But the gravitational constant can be expressed in parsec, kilometers per second and solar mass.But those are not the units the code uses to calculate the interactions

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_units

> In this system, the base physical units are chosen so that the total mass, M, the gravitational constant, G, and the virial radius, R, are normalized. The underlying assumption is that the system of N objects (stars) satisfies the virial theorem.

And in general you need three things to specify a unit system. So if Heggie suggested Hénon units for N body simulations and that's what you are trying to use then specify the mass as a fraction of the total mass. Specify each position as a fraction or multiple of the viral radius and then your time steps will be determined by $G.$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still don't understand how to determine the virial radius.

Comment: @linde Its probably supposed to be related to the average kinetic energy. Unless you look at the exact code used its hard to know for sure exactly. To make it easy to use, they might have programmed it so the kinetic energy per particle is 1 in their units. But if I were you I'd just do some two body problems where you know the answer and figure it out. You should even be able to do some three bodies where you know the solution such as one central body with two equal masses on opposite sides going in circles the same direction. Or all in a line going in or out. Make sure it agrees on those.

Comment: The kinetic energy is 0.25. Well that's the total energy of the system. I'm now trying to make an input file of the earth. Due to the mass difference I presume the kinetic energy of the earth is 0.25 I'm not sure I can use that since that is the energy in the program after the data is converted